# Method whereRaw does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to use WhereRaw in my query builder, but I get the message `Method whereRaw does not exist.`

I'm currently using Laravel version 5.5.40 with php version 7.0.30

This is the query I'm trying to make:

```
$places = Places::with('locations.places')->get()->whereRaw( 'LOWER(`title`) like ?', $id );
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `get` executes the query so `whereRaw` should come before that

Comment: @apokryfos I'm so dumb, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$places = Places::with('locations.places')->whereRaw( 'LOWER(`title`) like ?', $id )->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

WhereRaw method will come first and then get

```
$places = Places::with('locations.places')->whereRaw( 'LOWER(`title`) like ?', $id )->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$places = Places::with('locations.places')->whereRaw(DB::raw('LOWER(`title`) like ?', $id ))->get();
```